# Batch buffer with Python in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, buffer

I have some feature classes (7 feature classes) and I want to batch buffer in ArcGIS 10. I don't know how can I buffer at once.  Please help me.

Comment: Remember that arcpy does not handle memory issues very well. If you have big tasks (complex/many features) you might end up with the message: "There is not enough memory."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To buffer several features, you need to use some control structure. A technique I have found very useful is to store all of the shapefiles you are using in one folder, then loop through everything that is a shapefile. I do this using the `glob` module, as follows:

```
# import modules
import arcpy, glob

# folder where shapefiles are stored
folder = 'C:/myfiles/'

# loop through all shapefiles
for shapefile in glob.glob( folder + '*.shp' ):
     arcpy.Buffer_analysis( shapefile, "C:/output/" + shapefile[-8:-4] + "buffer.shp" "100 Feet", "FULL", "ROUND", "LIST", "Distance")
```

(See ArcGIS help [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000.htm) for more details)

I'm using an awkward way of naming the buffered file here (`shapefile[-8:-4]`); a better way is to set the workspace using something like `arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"`.

Comment: Should have read @jburka's answer more carefully before posting!

Answer (score 4):

As someone else already pointed out, you can use the Batch option by right-clicking the tool in Toolbox.  Otherwise, it's hard to know how best to batch it without knowing more about the feature classes and their locations (are they all in the same workspace?  are they the only feature classes in that workspace?) and the type of buffers you want to create (e.g. will they all have the same distance)

These things all go into, for instance, whether you're better off just typing in the name of a few feature classes into a list or if you should be using something like `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` to generate a list of feature classes to process.

Something as simple as:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'path\to\workspace'
featureClasses = ['fc1', 'fc2', 'fc3']
for featureClass in featureClasses:
  arcpy.Buffer_analysis(featureClass, "C:/output/" + featureClass + "Buffered" "100 Feet", "FULL", "ROUND", "LIST", "Distance")
```

would likely take care of it...

Answer (score 3):

To batch buffer in ArcMap 10 you can use the built in tools.  Just browse to Buffer in ArcToolbox (Analysis Tools < Proximity < Buffer), right-click the buffer tool and select batch.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I couldn't edit my comment properly; this is how I would go

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'path\to\workspace'   
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  

try:  
    for fc in fcs:  
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, outBufferFeatureClass, "X meters")  
except:  
    print "Error buffering FeatureClasses."`
```

I hope that helps.  You will have to thread if you want to do it all at the same time.

Comment: can you plaese Edit or comment back with `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) for Input folder` | `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) for Buffer(Double)` |`arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) for outputfolder` `          arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, outputfolder+ fc", buffer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ESRI [Buffer/ArcPy link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000.htm).  Here you will find some general code examples.

Comment: thanks but there is not example for buffering more than one feture class at once

Comment: @GISlove Why would you need to buffer more than one feature class at a time? Just curious.

Comment: i want to learn for and while loop in python . this is the reason for batch buffering

Comment: @GISlove Ah, I thought you meant that you wanted to run all of the buffering jobs simultaneously. Batch buffering via python makes more sense.

Comment: If you want to do them all at the same time, you'll have to put it into threads.

Comment: If you are buffering, I'd avoid using the dissolve option at buffering and dissolve once it is buffered. I have been working with buffering and dissolvign and imo, buffering and dissolving at the same time is very aggresive on the puter. Buffer, then dissolve and performance is much better.  I would also use arcpy.env.workspace = r'path\to\workspace' 
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
L = []

try:
    for fc in fcs:
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, outBufferFeatureClass, "X meters")
except:
    print "Error buffering FeatureClasses."

Answer (score 1):

The `Buffer` tool does not work on more than one feature class at a time. If you want to buffer all the features in multiple feature classes, you will have to either merge the feature classes into one combined feature class and buffer that, or buffer each of the individual feature classes in a loop.